# Ativando virtualenv no Makefile

Tags: makefile

Como eu faço para ativar o virtualenv no Makefile?

Tentei

```
venv:
    @virtualenv venv

active:
    @source venv/bin/activate
```

Tentei também

```
active:
    @. venv/bin/activate
```

E nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ative pelo bash criando um alias no `.bashrc`.